# javascript If an hour between two hours

Tags: javascript

Because the night begins at sunset and ends at sunrise, I need to determine if the current hour is after sunset and before sunrise. The time format is 24.

```js
var current = new Date();
current.setHours(0);
var sunset = new Date();
sunset.setHours(16); 
var sunrise = new Date();
sunrise.setHours(7); 
if(current >= sunset && current < sunrise ){
    console.log("yes!");
}else{
    console.log("no");
}
```

Another way to deal with hours as numbers

```js
currentHour= Number('0')
sunset= Number('16')
sunrise= Number('7')
let night = (currentHour >= sunset && currentHour < sunrise) ? true : false

console.log(night)
```

Comment: With `current.setHours(0);`, the `current` object doesn't even represent the current hour.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `new Date` if all you want to compare is two hour values. You would need to put `sunset` on the previous day, or `sunrise` on the next day, depending on the current time, if you wanted to check whether the current time is *between* them. Much too complicated. Just use

```
const currentHour = new Date().getHours();
const sunset = 16;
const sunrise = 7;
const isNight = currentHour < sunrise || currentHour >= sunset;
```

Your second snippet was a closer attempt, but you need to change this into an `OR` condition - it's either still night or already night *on the current day*.

Comment: This will also fail for the some time, like one minute after the sunrise.

Comment: @Nitheesh No? One minute after sunrise, 07:01, `currentHour` is `7` and `isNight` will be `false` as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Logical Error !!!

Sunrise and sunset should be on different days. If you are checking the time is after the sun set and before the sunrise on the next day, you have to consider, the sunrise to be on the next day and the sunset on today.

**Working code**

```js
var current = new Date();
current.setHours(0);
var sunset = new Date();
sunset.setHours(16);
sunset.setDate(sunset.getDate() - 1)
var sunrise = new Date();
sunrise.setHours(7);
if (current >= sunset && current < sunrise) {
  console.log("yes!");
} else {
  console.log("no");
}
```

Comment: This does not work. Why are you setting the `current` hours to 0? That way it's always night, even when it shouldn't be.

Comment: @Bergi, answer is very simple, the user was trying to set some custom value for the current time so that he can test the different cases. I followed the same pattern. If you just need to check the current instant time, you can just avoid that setTime(0)

Comment: Ah, maybe? But it still doesn't work in the evening.

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean by that?

Comment: At 20 o'clock, it is night already so the code should log "*yes*", but it doesn't because `current` is larger than `sunrise`. As you write yourself, "*you have to consider, the sunrise to be on the next day and the sunset on today*", while your code actually does consider the sunset on the previous day and the sunrise on today.

Comment: @Bergi This is just a simple solution of one case. There will be a hell lot of scenarios. I took only the case *the sunrise to be on the next day and the sunset on today.*

Comment: There's really only 3 different scenarios: the morning, the day, and the evening. I'm pretty sure OP expects all cases to be handled. If not, please at least add a disclaimer to your answer.

Comment: @Bergi Please read the answer description and see the disclaimer.